How to set the output of a high side driver to a desired level when the input signal is low and there’s no load on the output
I am studying a VN5010AK, which I control via a microcontroller that sets the INPUT to either 0 or 5V for switching purposes.
When the system is powered on but the input is not enabled, the driver output defaults to 8V if there is no load connected. When I enable the input, the output rises to 24V (the driver’s supply voltage).
If there is a load connected to the output and the input is at a low level, the output voltage drops to 0V. I assume this behavior is some form of protection, but I would like to know if it is possible to calculate this 8V output level.
I’m unsure whether this value can be calculated based on the sense leakage current, or if it is a parameter due to some pull-up or pull-down resistance contributing to this voltage drop at the unloaded output when the input is low.
Datasheet: https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/389/cd00151721-1796588.pdf


Please edit the question and describe why you care about what voltage the output is at. Presumably, it is meant to power a load, so without the load the voltage could be anywhere and it changes nothing?

It was just out of curiosity that I wanted to know if it was possible to calculate the output voltage under no-load conditions. This no-load voltage isn’t causing any problems; it’s more about understanding the driver’s behavior and operation. Thanks for all

When there's no load and the driver is turned off, the output is floating as it's essentially connected to nothing. This means that it'll take on a random voltage due to various leakage currents. The chip specifies a maximum off-state leakage current of 5µA (page 9, electrical characteristics), and it's this current that causes the weird voltage at the output. You can't calculate the resulting voltage as it's highly dependent on parasitics (output impedance and leakage).
If the floating output voltage is an issue, you can easily combat it by connecting a pull-down resistor from the output to ground, i.e. 100k Ohms. That'll result in a maximum off-state voltage of 0.5V (assuming 5µA of leakage) and an on-state current through the resistor of 240µA (dissipating around 6mW). If 0.5V is still too much, you could go down to 22k Ohms.

Thank you very much for your response. I knew that leakage currents played a significant role here, and I thought I might be able to estimate them based on
C_sense or some other signals from the driver.
Thank you for the example you provided and the information, it will definitely be useful to keep this in mind for future applications.
